# Overloading type with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following implementation

```
export class DbService<T extends object> {

    addOne<TKey extends keyof T>(table: TKey, object: T[TKey]) {
        return this.db.table(String(table)).add(object);
    }

}
```

It works fine when you give a valid interface as T:

```
interface DbSchema {
    users: User
}

var db = new DbService<DbSchema>();

// working fine here.
// It asks for 'users' key that matches the DbSchema
// And asks for User object implementation
db.addOne('users', { name: 'foo' });
```

But now I wish that `DbSchema` interface could be optional and you could give any key as table. So I tried the following overload method:

```
addOne<TKey extends keyof T>(table: TKey, object: T[TKey]): T[TKey];
addOne<O extends object>(table: string, object: O): O;
addOne(table: any, object: any) {
    return this.db.table(String(table)).add(object);
}
```

I can say that it partially worked, but typescript stopped from help me with the object implementation even when the key matches with the `DbSchema`.

It starts well, showing keys from `DbSchema`:

[image: test 1]

But when you start to write the object it loses the track and jumps to second overload:

[image: test 2]

Is there anything I can do to help it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that once you type `{}`, that's an empty object that doesn't match the `User` type, and the compiler immediately switches to the other overload, since `"users"` matches `string` and `{}` matches `object`.

One possible solution here is to make sure that the second overload *does not* accept known keys, like this:

```
  addOne<TKey extends keyof T>(table: TKey, object: T[TKey]): T[TKey];
  addOne<S extends string, O extends object>(table: S & Exclude<S, keyof T>, object: O): O;
  addOne(table: any, object: any) {
    return null!;
  }
```

Now the second overload has the `table` parameter as type `S & Exclude<S, keyof T>`, where [`Exclude<A, B>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetu) is a utility type that takes a union type `A` and removes any members that are assignable to `B`.  If `S` is a string distinct from `keyof T`, then `S & Exclude<S, keyof T>` will be `S & S` which is just `S`.  But if `S` is itself assignable to `keyof T`, then `S & Exclude<S, keyof T>` will be `S & never`, which is `never`.

The parameter `S` will be inferred as the string literal value passed in for `table`.  That means as long as `table` is not in `keyof T`, then `table` will be checked against `S`, which is fine.  But if `table` is in `keyof T`, then `table` will be checked against `never`, which is an error.  So as soon as you pass something like `"users"` in for `table`, the compiler will decide that it does not match the second overload.  And therefore when you are in the middle of typing `{}`, the compiler has no reason to switch to the second overload, and you get the desired IntelliSense:

[image: Good IntelliSense for addOne(table: "users", object: User)]

Hope this works for you or at least gives you some ideas.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiBGBlApgJwG4EtjIDwBVpkAPAF2QDsATGAe3gCtlhSA+aAbwChpowqqAeQp58AaWQBPImUo1oAaym0AZtHysAFKTDwQyAFzqJkgDTR6TFkfwBtcVIC6AShv2TjgNw8+A4XkQZcmoYCFJUTAoAc3NBILk6RmY2bV19I0CAMmgAUWJQAFcqAPMlSVV1VnNLZKNBV2hBb15+IRFUvUM+CjMLJOtuyWdOH15UZFIC1ApoCgKQEABCZugAXy51rkjyVBUwHDgkYAALZABbMBHeAog0CCMAVVvUb03ttD2Dp7Qr2bAzrphCLRDZcdBgVDQKjwaAAXlmyAA7ocUBhsHgEIgTucwFpnN4uNCAHStfyaADkNzu5PMHD+AKM5JUtFo5LW+OgAHpOdBvqhCfASX52gAiKi0KIi2l8IwARnZni5PI4YCMczO8DQmyAA)

Comment: Awesome! You helped me a lot! Thanks!!